# Query to show all Quarters / Year but to include both count of a column that has yes and no values

Tags: google-sheets

I have a query that shows Quarter and Items Purchased. I would like to show count values of an additional column, resale, that has yes or no values. The desired output is:

| Quarter | Items Purchased | Used for Resale | Not Used for Resale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-Q2 | 36 | 5 | 31 |
| 2021-Q1 | 50 | 3 | 47 |
| 2020-Q4 | 29 | 0 | 29 |

I don't want to overcomplicate. using count(resale) as it just gives me the count of the entire column in my query doesn't yield the results. Am i missing something straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert the raw data to the desired form using the array formula `if(C:C="Yes",1,)`
and then the query will look like this

`=ArrayFormula(query({A:B,if(C:C="Yes",1,)},"select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3), sum(Col2)-sum(Col3) group by Col1"))`

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to follow up the if statement made life very easy within a Query(Filter... So thanks for that!